How should we call our chat room?
Other sites have asked a similar question. I was thinking of simply writing 中文 but I thought it might be interesting to ask others about it.
What name would you like for our chat room? 

Since only one proposal was given, I accepted that one. Everyone, though, is still able to propose their ideas and maybe we'll come back to this someday.

If we wanted to go with something Chinese, why not 聊天 or 中文聊天? However, I notice that both the Japanese and German sites still have English names for their chat rooms. Anybody know if that's a conscious choice or they just haven't gotten around to changing yet?

I don't know. We might ask but it's not that we must follow what they did. :D The chat name has a description too and in case, we can use that. :) What do those names mean by the way?

They mean "chat" and "Chinese chat".

Many Chinese learners don't know Chinese characters at all (they learnt through pinyin only), so giving a Chinese name to the chat room is not a good idea. The Japanese and German sites got it right.

Why not name it after a famous (real or fictional) tea house or gathering place? Like "Mos Eisley" for SciFi SE. Or even some pun related like 河蟹 (river crab) for 和谐 (referring to Confucius-related philosophy of a harmonious society). Something meaningful -- in spirit of the name plaques that hang over temple/shop/inn entrances.
列： 捕语屋 （a play on the children's song 捕鱼歌）

I think we should do it like this:
Main chat for all things Chinese site-related should have an English name:
Chinese Language and Usage Chat

Chat room intended for PURE Chinese chat (very little English allowed) should have a Chinese name:
中文聊天室

Chat room for Chinese chat/discussion using English and Chinese + voice
中文会话室 

If needed, dedicated chat room intended for Chinese culture/traditions discussion
Chinese Culture and Traditions Chat


会话室, I can understand but I don't see a lot of it. For voice chat rooms, 语音聊天室 may be better. Also, if you add 中文 at the beginning, it seems that only Chinese can be used.
